# Downvotes löschen

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Kann mir bitte jemand die downvotes in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40432/is-afghanistan-really-the-8th-most-used-proper-noun-in-german-leipzig-byu-corp/40455#40455) löschen? Der OP hat sich zweimal bei mir bedankt, trotzdem hat mir ein Ungustl Downvotes gegeben...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nein, Downvotes können nicht gelöscht werden.**

Bitte nimm Dir die Zeit, [unsere Tour zu lesen](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour). Dort wird unter anderem erklärt, wie Voting funktioniert.

Nur das "Akzeptieren" einer Antwort kann einzig durch den Fragesteller erfolgen. Upvotes und Downvotes können zwar auch vom Fragesteller kommen, sie stammen aber in der Regel von anderen Mitgliedern, die hier das Privileg zum "Voten" haben. [Upvotes](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) kannst Du schon mit 15 Reputationspunkten vergeben, für [Downvotes](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) brauchst Du mindestens 125 Reputationspunkte, solltest also ein wenig mit der Seite vertraut sein.

Jedes Vote ist geheim (auch für uns Moderatoren!) und bleibt völlig im Ermessen des Einzelnen. Nur das Mitglied, das ein Downvote vergeben hat, könnte es auch wieder löschen, falls sich der Grund dafür z.B. durch ein Edit der Antwort, geändert hat. **Er muss dies aber nicht** und leider wird ein großer Teil der nicht-gerechtfertigten Downvotes nie zurückgenommen.

Du hast aber immerhin eine Chance, das der Downvoter irgendwann zu Deiner Antwort zurückkommt, sieht, dass Du sie verbessert hast, und daraufhin sein Downvote zurücknimmt (oder sogar in ein Upvote umwandelt).

Manchmal gibt ein Benutzer Dir in einem Kommentar Hinweise, was Du verbessern könntest. Du kannst Dich zum Beispiel bei dem Kommentator für diesen Hinweis bedanken und den Hinweis in die Antwort einbauen. Falls es derselbe war, der den Downvote verteilt hatte, wird er vermutlich seinen Downvote zurücknehmen. Auf jeden Fall wird dadurch aber Deine Anwort besser, auch wenn es sich nicht gleich in Reputationspunkten bemerkbar macht.

Wenn Du Deine Antwort löschst, dann werden auch die Reputationspunkte durch Upvotes gelöscht.

Diese Frage & Antwort (auf Englisch) ist auch ganz interessant zu diesem Thema:

- [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)
- https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15080/what-is-your-consideration-when-downvoting-what-are-your-criteria

Comment: Da voting subjektiv ist, behaupte ich einfach mal, dass es keine *nicht-gerechtfertigten Downvotes* gibt. Ob andere mit einer solchen Rechtfertigung überzeugt werden können, ist eine andere Geschichte.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: es sind die Votes gemeint, die auch nach einem grundlegenden Edit immer noch stehen bleiben, selbst wenn der Grund für den Downvote beseitigt wurde. Da kann man dann halt nichts machen.

Comment: Ah, ja klar, hätte ich auch selber drauf kommen können... stimmt schon. Aber aus solchen Gründen wiegt ja ein Downvote auch nur ein fünftel von einem Upvote (oder zwei fünftel im Falle von Fragen).

Comment: @Martin: Nur was die Reputationspunkte betrifft. Beim Up/Down-Netto wiegen sie gleichviel. Und bei den Votecountern (gesamt, speziell für Fragen).